# How to make an intricate multi-buffer search?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, icicles

In Python's regex dialect (correct terminology?) we have [`(?<=...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which can be used to narrow down searches with respect to what precedes a given pattern.

Trying this on Emacs to perform some intricate multi-buffer searching e.g. search only those buffers whose *content* contain `"x"` and/or `"y"` and then search the *content* of the matching buffers for `"foo"` and list the results, wasn't fruitful since:

```
(multi-occur-in-matching-buffers "." "\\(?<=:x\\|y\\)foo")
```

didn't match anything.

The [*Regexp Syntax Summary*](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html) states that it is not available GNU Emacs/Elisp.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you so this in two stages? Collect a list of buffers which contain a match for the first query, then create a regex of the buffer names to search for the second expression in.

Comment: @tripleee question updated

Comment: Slight update, `(multi-occur-in-matching-buffers "." "\\(x\\|y\\).*\\(\n.*\\)*foo\\|foo.*\\(\n.*\\)*\\(x\\|y\\)")` works for me, but of course, the regex isn't very elegant.  Unfortunately, `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` does not return a list of matches, so you'd have to parse the `*Occur*` buffer to do this in two steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

- `C-x b`, which chooses buffers, lets you also choose by their [***contents*** matching](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#MatchFileContent) your input pattern (which can be a regexp).  And it is a [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands#multi-command), which means that you can choose any number of buffers with a single use of `C-x b`.
- [Progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) lets you use any number of patterns (e.g. regexps), combining them to get their intersection (anding).  And you can subtract matches of other patterns (complementing).
- You can "mark" or "save" chosen buffers, as a set of [saved completion candidates](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets#toc2).  (You can even save such a set [persistently](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions).)

This means you can easily select all buffers that match both `x` and `y`.  Or if you want all that match `x` or `y`, just add those that match `y` to the buffers you marked for matching `x`.

Given that marked or "saved" set of buffers, you can then search for `foo` in them, using [**Icicles** search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) or vanilla Isearch.

On the other hand, if all you want to do is find buffers that match `foo` as well as `x` or `y`, then just use `C-x b`.  Note too that the last content-matching pattern (e.g., `foo`) you use for finding buffers is automatically saved as the last Isearch regexp.  So when you then visit the buffers you can immediately use `C-M-s` to search for individual occurrences.

Comment: I have twice attempted to bring Icicles into me work flow but it interfered with a lot of other packages. In fact, it became quite inconvenient to use and slowed done my work. So I had to get rid of it twice. I'll give it another try.

Comment: This looks like sure fire. Impressive. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for your trouble trying **Icicles**. As far as interference is concerned, in principle you can easily turn off pretty much any default **Icicles** behavior you like. Probably the place to start for that would be customizing option `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`. Setting that to `nil` means that **Icicles** does not bind *any* global keys. And all of the minibuffer keys it binds by default are also easily customizable. See [Icicles Key Bindings](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Bindings).  But yes, using *Icicle* minor mode means you will likely change the way you work.

Comment: Oops, I just checked [Drew Adams](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DrewAdams) and got the connection ;). It was MHO. Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely try them.

Comment: In "select all buffers that match both `x` and `y`", it is matching with the *name* of the buffer or it's *content*? Although I'm still trying but haven't succeeded in getting the desired result. Question updated.

Comment: To match `x` and `y`, use progressive completion: give pattern `x`, then hit `C-SPC` and give pattern `y`. You can match a pattern against buffer names or contents. To match contents, use `C-M-j` to move to the second multi-completion part. See: [searching named containers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Searching_Named_Containers), [multi-completions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions), [match names and content too](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#toc8), [buffer-name input](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input).

Comment: *searching named container* and `C-M-j` did it. Could you please incorporate them in the answer. Btw couldn't see the use `C-SPC`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `S-SPC`, not `C-SPC` -- see the doc about progressive completion.

Comment: I've now linked the answer to the doc that describes how to use `C-M-j` etc. to match buffer contents.